# Convert Excel to CSV using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to name new CSV files similar to their corresponding xlsx files

```
import pandas as pd

for filename in my_path.glob('*.xlsx'):

    read_file = pd.read_excel (str(filename)', sheet_name='My Excel sheet name')
    read_file.to_csv ("XLSX NAME SHOULD = CSV NAME.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: `import os`
`filename_without_extension = os.path.splitext(r'/path/to/some/file.xlsx')[0])`
And then use `os.path.join()` to create whatever you want

Comment: You have a quote wrongly placed, not sure if it's a typo here on SO or in your real code.: `str(filename)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the filename with path but without extension use `os.path.splitext`

```py
from os import path 

path = "/path/to/file.txt"
path.splitext(path)
# -> ["/path/to/file", "txt"]
```

To get the filename without the path :

```py
from os import path 

path = "/path/to/file.txt"
path.basename(path)
# -> "file.txt"
```

So to change the extension from `xlsx` to `csv` :

```py
from os import path 

path = "/path/to/file.xlsx"
filename = path.splitext(path)[0] + '.csv'
# -> "/path/to/file.csv"
```

And if you need to change the path to save the file in another folder, then you can use basename first.

Comment: I have multiple files that need to be converted not sure if this helps

Comment: Then you just need to put this in a loop with `for filename in my_path.glob('*.xlsx'):`

Comment: Thanks, also could you please take look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70985695/way-too-long-to-finish-the-execution-python-pandas